In Snowflake, how do I parse a JSON object?
In Snowflake, how do I parse a JSON object? I would like to separate the JSON object whenever this sequence "", occurs within it.
Below is my array.
[
  "JOE_SMITH 14:29:02",
  " CHANGEDBY: JANE_DOE -> JOE_SMITH",
  " CHANGEDATE: 2/21/2024 -> 2/24/2024",
  "",
  "JOE_SMITH 14:29:02",
  " OPENORDER: TRUE -> FALSE"
]

Below is what I tried and it didn't work:
SPLIT(Array)
Below is what I'm expecting. Parse the data into multiple JSON objects or varchar strings is fine for me.
[
  "JOE_SMITH 14:29:02",
  " CHANGEDBY: JANE_DOE -> JOE_SMITH",
  " CHANGEDATE: 2/21/2024 -> 2/24/2024",]
[
  "JOE_SMITH 14:29:02",
  " OPENORDER: TRUE -> FALSE"
]


Please try the below query and see if it helps:
WITH example_array AS (
  SELECT '[
  "JOE_SMITH 14:29:02",
  " CHANGEDBY: JANE_DOE -> JOE_SMITH",
  " CHANGEDATE: 2/21/2024 -> 2/24/2024",
  "",
  "JOE_SMITH 14:29:02",
  " OPENORDER: TRUE -> FALSE"
]' AS json_array
)

SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '""', '')) AS json_objects
FROM
  example_array,
  LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(json_array, ',') 
WHERE
  value <> '';


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
